# How do I define this subset using mathematical notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $P = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23,....\}$ or in another words, P is the set consisting of all prime numbers.

Now, suppose we want to form the set $S$, which is subset of $P$,and  whose elements are the first 100 prime numbers.
**How do I define subset S using mathematical notation?**

My two attempts were:

1. $S = \{x \in P \mid x ≤ m\}$ (where m is the 100th prime number) This method will only work when we know the *exact value* of m.
2. $S = \{x_{i} \in P \mid  1 ≤ i ≤ 100\}$ (I believe this method is also incorrect, as sets do not support indexing)

So what will be the correct way of defining subset $S$?

Comment: As you have started to note, i depends what mathematical notation is allowed, and you need to be clearer about what your starting point is. After all you need enough mathematical notation to define $P$ in the first place.

Comment: Also, what is the *goal* of this question? Often describing the set $S$ as just what it is, using natural language, is many times more clear than using convoluted mathematical expressions, just because it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

First, let me point out that I agree with your objections to the two approaches given in the question. (1) requires us to first define $m$ in some way, and (2) doesn't make sense.

Generally, I agree with @Vsotvep: The best way of describing $S$ is to write something using plain English, like "the set of the first 100 prime numbers" or "the set of the 100 smallest primes". But of course, there are infinitely many ways you can express this in a more complicated way by referring to $P$. Just two examples:

- $S$ is the unique subset of $P$ such that $|S| = 100$ and $S = \{ p \in P : p \le M\}$ for some real number $M$.
- $S$ is the unique subset of $P$ satisfying $|S| = 100$ and $\sum_{s \in S} s \le \sum_{x \in X} x$ for every subset $X$ of $P$ such that $|X| = 100$.

But I also agree with @Henning Makholm: You seem already to have defined the *sequence* of prime numbers, since you refer to things like "the *first* 100 prime numbers" and "the *100th* prime number". Just give this sequence a symbol, such as $(p_i)_{i=1}^\infty$, and you can also write

$$S = \{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_{100}\}$$

or, if you want it to look just slightly more complicated,

$$S = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{100} \{p_i\}.$$

(Also correct, but rather clumsy: $S = \{ p \in P : p \le p_{100}\}$.)

---

When writing mathematics, the goal is that the text should be easy to understand and precise -- you should always know exactly what is intended, how symbols are defined, etc., and the text should not contain any logical errors, ambiguities, etc. This is much more important than always using symbols -- symbols are used when they *aid* in the aforementioned goal.

*Bonus discussion.* You wrote

> Assume $P = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, \dots.\}$ or in another words, $P$ is the set consisting of all prime numbers.

Here I do see a small deviation from rigour. Can you spot it? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As to your question, I would guess there is something wrong in "$P$ is the set consisting of **all** prime numbers". Because there is infinite number of primes, so, maybe it would be more rigorous to say that "$P$ is *infinite* set consisting of prime numbers." Is this a deviation? Or is there something else?

Comment: @Nelver: No, I think it is perfectly OK to talk about "the set consisting of all prime numbers". The thing I had in mind was rather the "or in other words" part. To me, this phrase means that the subsequent text contains the same information as the text before it, just described in a different way. But while $P = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, \dots.\}$ doesn't really define $P$ unambiguously (there are infinitely many sequences starting with these 9 elements, even some that can be described rather simply), the phrase "the set consisting of all prime numbers" defines $P$ unambiguously. (->)

Comment: (cont.) This, of course, is nitpicking, and I wouldn't had mentioned it had I not known you were interested in the language of mathematics and communicating mathematics. It really is a very small issue. Interestingly, however, I would find "let $P$ be the set consisting of all prime numbers, that is, $P = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, \dots.\}$" to be perfectly sound. The thing is that the ellipsis kind of means "and so on, in the way that is obvious from the context", and if this construction comes immediately after you have defined $P$ as the set of all primes, it really is obvious. :)

Comment: If we are to use the *most* concise and rigorous way to define set $P$, would "let $P$ be the set consisting of all primes numbers" be the best choice? As you've pointed out, "the set consisting of all prime numbers" defines $P$ unambiguously, so now I feel that "that is, $P = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23...\}$" clause should be discarded altogether.

Comment: @Nelver: I agree it's superfluous, and in a graduate-level text, mathematics journal article, etc., you'd not include it -- it very much doesn't add anything, it just makes the text longer. But if I'd write a textbook or article aimed at (junior) students of mathematics, I might still choose to include that part just for clarity. From a pedagogical/psychological point of view, it might feel more concrete if you actually write down the first actual prime numbers. (I mean, some students might not even know that 2 is the first prime number!)

Answer (score 10):

It is common to use the notation $p_i$ for the $i$th prime, so you could write
$$ \{p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots, p_{100} \} $$
Attempting to make it "more symbolic" (as if the mathematical notation were a programming language rather than a means of communicating ideas to human readers) will only make it *less clear* to your readers what you mean, and most probably will not serve any useful purpose.

Comment: Either that, or one can simply write "Let $S$ be the set of the first $100$ primes" to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of giving an abstract definition of the set of the first $100$ primes, is that you don't want to compute primes or use a lookup table. So in order to give the definition of the set of the first $100$ primes, it is no problem that you don't know the $100$'th prime, so I would say both approaches are fine, although I would replace $m$ in your first definition by ${x_{100}}$, or better yet, since we are talking about primes, $p_{100}$, where $p_{i}$ is the $i$'th prime.

Answer (score 0):

The set of primes are often defined as $\mathbb{P}$.
Afaik, the **proper subset** $S$ of the **superset** $\mathbb{P}$ is defined as:

Let $S \subset \mathbb{P}$. Then $s \in S$.

The notation $(s_n)_{n=1}^{100}$ denotes the $100$-term sequence of primes.

I think also you could write it as:

Let $S=[1,100]$, a closed interval of $\mathbb{P}$.

The interval is **right-closed** because it has a maximum. Could some expert re-edit my post if i got that last bit wrong.